# Class 'Pusher' not found in error in website

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast

So I made real time chat in laravel. I use version 5.4. All works fine in my local server. But when I uploaded files to real server(to my website) there is a problem.

So my env files in local is like this :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=xx
MAIL_USERNAME=xx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADRESS=xx
MAIL_FROM_NAME= "selam"

PUSHER_APP_ID=xx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xx
```

All works fine with this. But in my website, I get this error :

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'Pusher' not found

in BroadcastManager.php (line 216)
at BroadcastManager->createPusherDriver(array('driver' => 'pusher', 'key' => 'xx', 'secret' => 'xx', 'app_id' => '434070', 'options' => array('cluster' => 'eu', 'encrypted' => true)))
in BroadcastManager.php (line 193)
```

When I change

> BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher to BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

in website .env it works but without being real time..I tried to add 'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class, to config\app.php aliases but It didnt help. Also I tried to change use Pusher; to use Pusher\Pusher in broadcastmanager it also didnt help. How I can solve this problem I need your help?

composer.json

```
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.2",
        "laravel/dusk": "1.1",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~2.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
```

Comment: Did you *install* Pusher on the server? Per the docs, `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"` is needed (or a `composer install`).

Comment: Yes but I have "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~2.6" version. should I update it to 3.0?

Comment: Please, add a link the package you are using for Pusher.

Comment: what do you mean by package?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `composer.json` file? Specifically the `require` section.

Comment: ok i add now sec.

Comment: Thanks, have you run `composer install` on your server? You do have a `composer.lock` file on your server too, right?

Comment: yes I do have composer.lock. I think I ran composer install before, but should I do it again maybe?

Comment: That's good, your `composer.lock` file should tell composer what needs to be installed when you run `composer install`. Yes, I would give `composer install` another go to see if it fixes your problem

Comment: After running `composer install` also run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Hmm I tried, but seems like it didnt solve. I get same error. Maybe I should delete pusher and Install again? How I can do this?

Comment: Maybe try this package instead? https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-laravel

Comment: There is error when I try to install. But anyway I think this problem is about something else, any more ideas..? :/

Answer (score 2):

add `'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class,` in `aliases` array in config/app.php file